# How to connect 2 rails 5 apps together API (rails) and front-end (rails as well)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

As i mentioned on the question title, I want to know the best approach to get this to work and i'll need and example ( very simple one as the follow: )

Let's say i have an API which has 1 controller and 1 action for example simplicity

```
root 'main#index'
```

and inside the index action i have

```
def index
  @date = Data.today
end
```

Then i have another rails app which will work for front-end rendering

How can i pass this @date as JSON from the API to the other app to render it ?

Should i have same controller on the other app ?

How can i connect and send http request and receive response ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you may mean `@date = Date.today` (your version says Data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such a simple example, you can do something as simple as:

```
def index
  @date = Date.today
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json @date
  end
end
```

However, you're most likely going to want to deal with more complicated JSON responses, so before long you'll probably want to use something like the [Jbuilder gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [ActiveModel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) (my preferred approach).

On the other end, your front-end will need to make an HTTP GET request.  Lots of ways (and gems) to do this, but one common approach is just to use the built in `Net::HTTP` class.

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse('http://backend.dev/main/index')
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

raise response.body.inspect
```

In your situation, a better approach might be to use the [Active Resource gem](https://github.com/rails/activeresource).  This gem allows you to create models that are backed by a REST API rather than a database.  For example, if your API app provides basic Create-Read-Update-Destroy actions for a particular model (let's call it `Widget`) at the following URLs:

```
GET http://backend.dev/widget       # listing of widgets
GET http://backend.dev/widget/1     # Read for widget id: 1
POST http://backend.dev/widget      # Create new widget
UPDATE http://backend.dev/widget/1  # Update widget id: 1
DELETE http://backend.dev/widget/1  # Destroy widget id: 1
```

then in your front-end app you could declare an Active Resource like this:

```
class Widget < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://backend.dev"
end
```

which will auto-magically access all of those methods in your API, and behave much like a regular Active Record model.  That way, you basically design your front-end app like a "normal" rails app, but using ActiveResource-based models in place of ActiveRecord.

I would note, however, that a more common thing to do these days would be to build your API in Rails, and build your front-end with client-side Javascript, using something like JQuery or Angular to make requests from the API.  I'm not sure what you're gaining by splitting API and front-end, where both of them are Rails apps - unless you've got a compelling reason, I'd just build one Rails app that handles both API and front-end, or build a Rails API + Angular (or similar) front-end.

Comment: Well, the reason of this is that i want to create an API which handles all the logic and i want to have a real good front-end made with Angular, Thing is, i can't use angular comfortably now, so i have to split it and use rails as front end because it matches my current experience with front end, this will be some something like testing front end not a real one, I don't want my app to be monolithic so i can make it's front-end later, Also another question is where should i put this code you wrote ? may be i have some experience with rails but no on this part.

Comment: Okay, in this case, I might suggest using the ActiveResource gem, which basically lets you build models (like normal) that are backed by an API rather than a database.  That way, your front-end app will be structured much like a "normal" rails app.  I've added a section to my answer about that - but you'll want to look at the Active Resource readme carefully.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, or at least it solved a serious problem here, I tried it and it worked, I had some struggles and had to read the documentation and it worked for indexing entries and adding new entries to db, i guess it should go the same for update and delete, Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @drosboro the approach of building one rails app that handles both api and front-end is quite compelling, I need your help to do that